# Could this Runnable class cause memory leaks?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, memory-leaks, runnable

I have created a class and extended it with `Runnable`. This class is supposed to do operation in the background and post results on UI thread. However, the variables I am using this `Runnable` class belong to the outter class(Parent class). Example:

```
Class MainFragment {

 onStart() {

   val runnable = BackgroundRunnable()
   Thread(runnable).start()
 }


 private inner class BackgroundRunnable: Runnable {

    onRun() {
       //using MainFragment`s member variables here
      //performing background ops that can take more than 48ms
    }

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {

        override fun run() {
                //notfiyDataSetChanged()
          }

      }
  }

}
```

As you can see from above example code, I am using `inner` to access `MainFragment` class member variables. This would cause a memory leak? If so how to avoid it?

Here is the actual code I wrote:

```
private inner class BackgroundRunnable : Runnable {

        override fun run() {

            list!!.clear()
            listItems!!.clear()

            list = dbHandler!!.readAllNotes()

            for (noteReader in list!!.iterator()) {
                val note = UserNotes()

                note.noteTitle = noteReader.noteTitle
                note.noteText = noteReader.noteText
                note.noteID = noteReader.noteID
                note.noteColor = noteReader.noteColor
                note.noteEncrypted = noteReader.noteEncrypted
                note.noteCheckList = noteReader.noteCheckList
                note.noteDate = noteReader.noteDate
                note.noteTempDel = noteReader.noteTempDel
                note.noteArchived = noteReader.noteArchived
                note.noteReminderID = noteReader.noteReminderID
                note.noteReminderText = noteReader.noteReminderText

                listItems!!.add(note)
            }



            activity!!.runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {

                    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    return
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

**Using Weak reference**

```
private class BackgroundRunnable internal constructor(context: NotesFrag) : Runnable {

        private val weakReference = WeakReference(context)

        override fun run() {

            val parentClass = weakReference.get()


            parentClass!!.list!!.clear()
            parentClass.listItems!!.clear()

            parentClass.list = parentClass.dbHandler!!.readAllNotes()

            for (noteReader in parentClass.list!!.iterator()) {
                val note = UserNotes()

                note.noteTitle = noteReader.noteTitle
                note.noteText = noteReader.noteText
                note.noteID = noteReader.noteID
                note.noteColor = noteReader.noteColor
                note.noteEncrypted = noteReader.noteEncrypted
                note.noteCheckList = noteReader.noteCheckList
                note.noteDate = noteReader.noteDate
                note.noteTempDel = noteReader.noteTempDel
                note.noteArchived = noteReader.noteArchived
                note.noteReminderID = noteReader.noteReminderID
                note.noteReminderText = noteReader.noteReminderText

                parentClass.listItems!!.add(note)
            }



            parentClass.activity!!.runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {

                    parentClass.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    return
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-static inner classes can leak memory if they outlive the container object.
In your case, `Fragment` will not get GC'ed until the `Runnable` is finished because the inner class is holding an implicit reference to the containing `Fragment`.

To solve this, generally the recommendation is to hold on to a `WeakReference` to the object from which you would need data from the containing class or a `WeakReference` to the Activity/Fragment, if you are accessing the Activity/Fragment directly (like you do with `getActivity()` in the `Runnable`).

Comment: So how do I get a weak reference? Do I have to write "BackgroundRunnable internal constructor(context: Context)" in Runnable class?

Comment: Please check the original post, tried it using weak reference

Comment: Yup, should be good once you add the null checks on the object you get from `WeakReference.get()`.

 `val parentClass = weakReference.get() ?: return`

And a ?. safe access on the activity- parentClass.activity?.runOnUiThread(..)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to leak memory. But the best way to make sure of it is to test it. Run it many times and see if the memory increases. Is there any reason making you think that is it leaking?

On a different note, you should probably avoid unwrapping everything and keep the optionals instead (meaning using `?` instead of `!!`).

Comment: Yes the memory consumption is increasing on every run.

Comment: `list = dbHandler!!.readAllNotes()`, This line may be leaking stuff. I don't know the implementation, though. Try to comment out your code to isolate the problem. Try also to manually trigger a GC. Usually, the memory is not released immediately.